# vue3, echarts.apache, remove circle dots

Tags: vuejs3, echarts

I have a graph with a lot of data. In this graph, the lines have round dots at their ends. How to remove them?

[image: 1]

Now the graph looks like this. I can't find any settings that would help me get rid of the dots.

I found this. https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-line.symbol
But I don't know if it is. And how to write it down. My settings look like this:

```
const line: any = {
  type: 'line',
  data: this.store,
  yAxisIndex: 0,
}

this.options = {
  color: ['#a58e18'],
  animationDuration: 300,
  title: {
    text: 'Raw Flows',
    left: '1%',
    top: '5px',
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'time',
    show: false,
  },
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'axis',
    axisPointer: {
      type: 'shadow',
    },
  },
  grid: {
    left: '5px',
    right: '35px',
    bottom: '-10px',
    top: '10px',
    containLabel: true,
    show: false,
  },
  yAxis: [
    {
      type: 'value',
      nameTextStyle: {
        align: 'left',
      },
      splitLine: {
        show: false,
      },
    },
  ],
}
this.options.title.padding = [0, 0, 0, 0]
this.options.series = [
  line,
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured it out.

all i had to do was

const line: any = {
symbol: 'none',
}